# 'foreach' to perform an action for all the rows in a table

Tags: windows-phone-8, foreach, sql-server-ce

I have following class & DataContext Structure,

```
public class Accounts
{
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
}

class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
    public MyDataContext (string ConnectionString) : base(ConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public Table<Accounts> AllAccounts
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<Accounts>();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get all the accounts from 'Accounts Table' and use each of their SecretKeys to get PIN and show all those accounts in list box...

Problem is I cant create foreach statement

something like

```
foreach (AllAccountsAC in MyDataContext.Accounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't do a `foreach` loop without typing the variable.  For a `Table`, you would have to do the `foreach` on its rows:

```
Table t = new Table();
foreach (TableRow tr in t.Rows)
{
    //enter code here
}
```

Once you have the row you can get the data.

Second, you can't type a `Table`.  You could use a typed `List` (such as `List<Accounts>` for your class) and do the same thing, but use the type set in the `List`:

```
List<Accounts> AccountList = new List<Accounts>();
foreach (Accounts a in AccountList)
{
    //enter code here
}
```

Once you have the object from the list, you can perform any functions on it that you need.